# jQuery Selectors: Select element with specific class and 'title' attribute

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors, attributes, title

This should be an easy one, but I can't find a good example anywhere. I'm trying to select a particular element on my page that has a class of 'statuslight' and a title attribute of one of three options. The option (it will depend) is stored in a variable called 'currentStatus'. I've seen some examples, and I'm guessing this is the right track, but I need to know for sure:

```
$(".statuslight[title]='" + currentStatus + "'");
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Very close:

```
$(".statuslight[title='" + currentStatus + "']");
```

Supposing your `currentStatus` is an array, you could get all `statuslight` elements with a title that contains any of the `currentStatus` values with:

```
$(".statuslight[title='" + currentStatus[0] + "'], .statuslight[title='" + currentStatus[1] + "'], .statuslight[title='" + currentStatus[2] + "']");
```

Alternatively, if your title has multiple statuses (`title="status1 status2 status3"`), and `currentStatus` is only one item you would use this selector:

```
$(".statuslight[title~='" + currentStatus + "']");
```

Comment: Thanks Joel. `currentStatus` is not an array, just a simple string. I believe the top option should work. Thanks.

Comment: +1 needed this for customizing an encrypted source app that had no classes or IDs on my target elements. I was able to use $("a[title='test']").attr("href","hxxp://mycustomurl.com")